# refreshing workspace in eclipse after changing strings in strings.xml (for android project)

Tags: android, eclipse, string, refresh

I'm new to android and eclipse. I'm building a simple project. The problem is, when I change a string in the strings.xml file, the changes do not appear in the workspace until I close and restart the software. I tried using manual refresh and i even checked the preferences->general->workspace->refresh on access. But nothing happens until i restart eclipse.

What changes should I make to see the changes immediately after modifications of strings in other files?

Thank you.

Comment: did you try Project-> Build Automatically and check it

Comment: yes, it was already checked

Comment: Try cleaning the project

Comment: as Kushwaha said below project -> build automatically but what i want you to try is to uncheck it and then right click in your project and select Build project 
this will build it manually

Comment: @ user1283633, I did exactly as you told and it works! do you think it's a bug in eclipse or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

@Kushwaha is right

select this option

`Project-> Build Automatically` and check it

Comment: It was already checked, but i still unchecked and checked it, but its not working. I tried cleaning it as well as refreshing, but the graphical layout remains same as when I started eclipse

Comment: which version do you have used of eclipse

Comment: The one I have is version 4.2.1